# Persist control values in gridview header asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview which is used to display information about links that are relevant for employees of the business that I work for.

My boss wants me to have the filtering controls in the header row of the gridview, but they do not persist their information through post-backs given that they are created dynamically.

So how do I go about accomplishing this?

If it at all helps, the controls I need to persist are a textbox and a dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

To persist your information in `GridView`, use `Session` or `ViewState`.

Comment: ViewState is enabled on all of the controls in question. I assume that the problem is that they are dynamically created, correct?

So I have to manipulate viewstate manually to do this properly, is that correct?

Comment: you want to create controls dynamically in code-behind. what does mean by persisting control?